# I am trying to send the values of array from .m file in objective C to Html or Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, objective-c

I am trying to send the values of array from .m file in objective C to **Html or Javascript**.

This is my **Objective C** code in .m file,

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Array"ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"csv"];
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,"]];
        for (NSString* line in lines) {

                 NSLog(@"%@", line);


                }
                NSLog(@" %d", [lines count]);
        [self.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Contents = new Array%@",lines] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The following is my Javascript function in the HTML page,

```
function Contents() {

                   alert(Contents[0]);


                    // at this point, the documentsDirectoryContent should have been created and filled with the files
                    if (typeof(Contents)=='undefined') // warning in case documentsDirectoryContent does not exist

                    else {
                        if (Contents.length == 0) // no files in the directory

                        else { // iterate through array to print file names
                            for (i=0; i<Contents.length; i++) {


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But when I run the App I am getting the following message in alert as undefined

I just want to know where I am doing the mistake in code or have I missed some code or any function.

Answer (score 0):

You have both your array, and the function to call it named 'Contents', so the function is overwriting the array. Change `function Contents() {` to `function checkContents() {` and call that. Let us know if that works!

Comment: Hi Beejamin, i tried it with what u said, it is not displaying anything not even the alert also.

Comment: you are calling checkContents() now, instead of just Contents() ? Sorry - your source code doesn't really help to debug too much. Can you link to the application, or a version of it? Even just saving the HTML page and linking to that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString];`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

### Objective-C

```
NSString * tmp = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{{some.array}}" withString:@"Your Array"];
```

### HTML / Javascript

Where you want to replace the text in this file, just add **`{{some.array}}`**.